# show only play button with animategraphics

Tags: animate, gif

I transformed a gif in a serie of png files and I animated it in my pdf with the command `\animategraphics`. I want to have only a play button shown, not all the controls. Is there a way of doing this?

Here is the full command that I used at the moment:

`\animategraphics[loop,width=\textwidth]{50}{./figures/sim_gif/res_gl_animation_}{0}{399}`

Thanks.

Edit:

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt, final]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \animategraphics[loop,width=\textwidth]{50}{./figures/sim_gif/res_gl_animation_}{0}{399}
    \caption{Some animation for MWE}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I edited my question. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Specific buttons from the available set of controls can be selected as follows:

> ```
> con­trols[=all | true | on]                 % show all avail­able but­tons
> con­trols=none | false | off                % hide them all
> con­trols={[play][, step][, stop][, speed]} % show se­lected
> ```

Thus, to show the play button alone,

```
controls=play
```

is sufficient.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\animategraphics[
  controls=play,
  width=1in,loop
]{1}{example-image-a4-numbered}{}{}
\end{document}
```

---

Alternatively, the JS API of `animate` can be used. It gives access to the animation objects in a PDF file.

The `\mediabutton` command from the `media9` package can be used to create custom buttons as in the code listed below.

Instead of Play/Pause strings, you can `\includegraphics` image files as button faces for the Play and Pause buttons, or draw something with TikZ.

A *single* toggle button for play-pausing an animation is given in [Fig. 1](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf#nameddest=figure.1) in the `animate` docs. Here, two buttons, one for play, another for pause are inserted below the animation:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt, final]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \animategraphics[label=myAnim,loop,width=\textwidth]{50}{./figures/sim_gif/res_gl_animation_}{0}{399}

    \mediabutton[jsaction={anim.myAnim.playFwd();}]{\fbox{\strut Play}}
    \mediabutton[jsaction={anim.myAnim.pause();}]{\fbox{\strut Pause}}
    \caption{Some animation for MWE}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note that 50 frames per second, as specified in OP's example, is way too much and will hardly be achieved by AdobeReader. FPS 20 is sufficient for smooth playback (FPS 25 is a typical value for video encoding) and can be achieved if the image files are not too big and complex.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I taught it would be a bit simpler, but your answer really helps. I can't seem to make it work tho, it raised an error saying it can't fing the `media9.sty`.

Comment: @user2482876: `media9` is in TeXLive-2012 and 2013, and in MiKTeX. You should update your TeX installation.

Comment: @user2482876: If you really want the reader to just start an animation, clicking onto it is enough.

Comment: @AlexG: Or I can just put autoplay in the option. I knew about that but I wanted to see if it was possible to have just a play/pause button, making it more obvious to the reader that the figure is an animation.